# Opening a form programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winforms project and I need to open another form on the click of a button on the main form (Form1).

What is the C# to do this?

Answer (score 8):

. . .

```
Form2 newForm = new Form2();
newForm.Show();
//or newForm.ShowDialog();
```

...

Comment: Yep. That's as simple as it gets. =)